# Compiler for grond, a language-in-the-making

Tags: javascript, regex, compiler, language-design

I'm working on a language called grond ([see it on GitHub](https://github.com/epicTCK/Grond/tree/0958b3fa08294f63ea082a2301ef0890d3f09ebe)); the compiler is so small it is included in this post.

My gut tells me that this code is *awful*, but it works. I am hesitant to change things to make the code better because generally, I have found that bad things happen when I "fix" something that isn't necessarily broken.

How can I make this "ugly" code better? Note - If you don't think this code is ugly, please tell me!

```js
String.prototype.reverse = function() {
  return this.split("").reverse().join("");
}

function replace(wc) {
  var lastWC;

  while (true) {
    lastWC = wc;
    wc = wc.reverse();
    wc = wc.replace("§", "");
    wc = wc.replace("Ś", "");
    wc = wc.replace(/\(a(?!\w)/, "(trela"); //alert ,a
    wc = wc.replace(/\(f(?!\w)/, "(rof"); // for, f
    wc = wc.replace(/\(w(?!\w)/, "(elihw"); //while,w
    wc = wc.replace(/\(p(?!\w)/, "(tpmorp"); //prompt,p
    wc = wc.replace(/\(vr\./, "(esrever."); //reverse, rv
    wc = wc.replace(/\(tm\./, "(chtam."); // match, mt
    wc = wc.replace(/\(nj\./, "(nioj."); //join, .jn
    wc = wc.replace(/\(pr\./, "(ecalper."); //replace, .rp
    wc = wc.replace(/\(ls\./, "(.ecils"); //slice, sl
    wc = wc.replace(/\(lt\./, "(esaCrewoLot."); //toLowerCase, tl
    wc = wc.replace(/\(ut\./, "(esaCreppUot."); //toUpperCase, tu
    wc = wc.replace(/\(ps\./, "(tilps."); //split, sp
    wc = wc.reverse();
    wc = wc.replace(/\.l(?!\w)/, ".length"); // .length, .l
    if (lastWC === wc)
      break;
  }
  return wc;
}

var source = prompt("Enter Source");
var sourceCopy = source;


var fullASCII = ' !#$%&()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~'.split('');
var y = (a) => {
  for (let char in fullASCII) {
    if (!source.contains(char)) {
      source.replace(a, char);
    }
  }
}
var OK = false;
var OK2 = false;
for (let char in fullASCII) {
  if (!source.contains(char)) {
    OK2 = OK ? true : false;
    OK = true;
  }
}
if (!OK2) {
  throw "Your program uses every ASCII charactor. Grond requires your program to leave 2 ASCII chars unused. This is stupid and will be fixed.";
}
y('\\\"');
y("\\\'");
var sourceSplit = sourceCopy.split("\'");
for (let i = 0; i < sourceSplit.length; i += 2) {
  var o = sourceSplit[i].split('\"');
  for (let e = 0; e < o.length; e += 2) {
    o[e] = replace(o[e]);
  }
  sourceSplit[i] = o.join('\"');
}
sourceCopy = sourceSplit.join("\'");

var append = "if(s != \"\"){alert(s)}";
var prepend = "var s = prompt();";
var oSS = source.split('');
if (oSS[0] == "§") {
  prepend = "var s = \"\"";
}
if (oSS[0] == "Ś" || oSS[1] == "Ś") {
  prepend = "with(math){" + prepend;
  append += "}";
}

sourceCopy = prepend + " String.prototype.la=function(h){var x=this.split(''); x[h] = x[h].toLowerCase(); return x.join('');};String.prototype.ca=function(h){var x=this.split(''); x[h] = x[h].toUpperCase(); return x.join('');};String.prototype.reverse=function(){return this.split('').reverse().join('');}; \n var h = ['hello, world', 'Hello, World', 'Hello, World!', 'hello, world!', 'hello world', 'hello world!', 'Hello World', 'Hello World!', 'Hello, world.', 'Hello, World.' ,'hello world.' , 'Hello World.'];  var q ='" + source + "'; " + sourceCopy + append;
alert(sourceCopy);
eval(sourceCopy);
```

Comment: yes, the code works as far as I have tested it...thanks for the feed back (and not the downvote... I assume that was you)

Comment: `prompt();`... you should click run code snippet or *read the code*...

Comment: I have made the edits on github, is it customary on code review to edit the post with the edits you suggested as well?

Comment: As long as there is no *answer*, feel free to update the question as you'd like.

Comment: This code doesn't work, because JavaScript doesn't have `String.prototype.contains` method.

Comment: I always get contains mixed up with `includes`, will switch around

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> String.prototype.reverse = function() {
>   return this.split("").reverse().join("");
> }
> ```

Firstly, [don't modify objects you don't own](https://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/03/02/maintainable-javascript-dont-modify-objects-you-down-own/). It could cause incompatibility problems if some other code had its own `String.prototype.reverse` function which had different functionality.

Secondly, this is [a bad implementation of reversing a string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16776621/3853934). For example, calling this function on the following string:

```
'foo  bar'
```

returns:

```
'rab �� oof'
```

---

You use many meaningless identifiers, for example `wc`, `y`, `OK`, `OK2`. It's hard to tell what purpose they serve.

---

> ```
> while (true)
> ```

Instead of using an infinite loop and `break`-ing it, I recommend you using a do-while loop. In your case it could look like that:

```
var condition = false
do {
  // the actual loop content

  condition = lastWC === wc
} while (!condition)
```

See [Is while (true) bad programming practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/390481/3853934).

---

I highly recommend you wrapping your code in an IIFE (see [Ben Alman's article](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) for more details). In the current state, all your variables are global, which is a bad practice. See [Why are global variables considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10525582/3853934).

---

I had to spend quite a while to work out how the `replace` function works. It seems that you wanted to re-invent the `g` regex modifier (read [MDN RegExp docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)). You could get rid of the loop at all if you used it.

I don't see any point in reversing the `wc` variable two times, except of making the code less readable.

Calling `wc.replace()` multiple times and assigning the result to `wc` looks ugly. You could at least chain the `.replace()` calls like that: `wc.replace(...).replace(...).replace(...)`, or even better, make an array of matches and replacements and loop through them:

```
var matchesAndReplacements = [
  ["§", ""]
 ,["Ś", ""]
 ,[/\(a(?!\w)/g, "(trela"]
]

for (let i of matchesAndReplacements) {
  let [match, replacement] = i
  wc = wc.replace(match, replacement)
}
```

And most importantly, this doesn't work. Writing a programming language compiler using regex is a very naive idea, and IMHO even worse than trying to [parse HTML with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348/3853934). A simple example: what if you had a `.l` fragment in a string? It would be incorrectly changed to `.length`.

---

> ```
> var source = prompt("Enter Source");
> ```

`prompt()` is a pretty primitive way to make an I/O. Even if you decide so, it shouldn't be somewhere in the middle of the code. Create a function, named `compile` for example, which takes input as argument and returns output, and then at the end of the code place `alert(compile(prompt("Enter Source")))`.

---

> ```
> var source = prompt("Enter Source");
> var sourceCopy = source;
> ```

When you declare multiple variables at once, you can use the `var` keyword only once, and separate the variables declarations with a comma, like that:

```
var source = prompt("Enter Source")
   ,sourceCopy = source
```

However, in this case it would be better to use [`const`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) for `source`, as you don't intend to modify it.

---

> ```
> var y = (a) => {
>   for (let char in fullASCII) {
>     if (!source.contains(char)) {
>       source.replace(a, char);
>     }
>   }
> }
> ```

If your arrow function has only one parameter, you don't need to use parentheses, so it could be `var y = a=> {}`.

Also, this function seems to be no-op, because it doesn't return any value and doesn't assign any value to any variable.

---

```
var OK = false;
var OK2 = false;
for(let char in fullASCII){
  if(!source.contains(char)){
    OK2 = OK? true:false;
    OK = true;
  }
}
```

That looks ugly for me. You could rewrite it like that:

```
const isOK = fullASCII.map(source.contains.bind(char)).filter(x=>x).length >= 2
```

One liners FTW!

---

> ```
> var sourceSplit = sourceCopy.split("\'");
> ```

You don't need to escape apostrophes if you use double quotes to make a string. Besides, I would name the variable `sourceSplitted`, because now it looks more like a function name.

---

> ```
> if (oSS[0] == "§") {
> ```

Always use `===` instead of `==`. See [Does it matter which equals operator (== vs ===) I use in JavaScript comparisons?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/359494/3853934).

---

To conclude: yes, this code *is* ugly. You have a lot to learn.

Comment: I reverse wc because javascript does not have negitive look-behinds, so I use a negitive look-ahead on the reversed string.

Comment: "what if you had a .l fragment in a string? It would be incorrectly changed to .length." I don't run replace() on strings. It's right in the code. I split by quotes and parenthises and run the even indices (0,2,4... etc) because the odd ones are enclosed in quotes.

Comment: Thanks for the help, `You have a lot to learn.` Yeah, I know, that's why I'm on code review getting advice from nice people like you ^_^. (I hate i when my comment sounds sarcastic but it isnt..)

Comment: @epicTCK What if you had a string enclosed in quotes with a quote character escaped by a backslash: `"\""`?

Comment: Trace the full ASCII variable. It replaces the escaped quotes with a character not used in the inputted program and remembers that character, <strike>then changes it back</strike> (I forgot to add that last bit in the code. I must have been tired... :P)

Comment: @epicTCK Meh. Did you know that JavaScript also has [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)?